# How do I affect generic class type refined by method call in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am writing type definitions for a library we'll name `library` which contains a generic interface `A` with a method `refine`, a new `A` object can be created by calling the `createA` function.

```
interface A<T> {
  refine<U extends T>(): A<U>
}

interface CreateA {
  <T extends any>(): A<T>;
}

const createA: CreateA;
```

We can now create new `A` objects constrained by either the initial `createA` function or the chained `refine` method.

```
createA<any>(); // A<any>
createA<any>().refine<number>(); // A<number>
```

How can I make TypeScript reference itself and refine it's type when the `refine` method is called.

```
const a = createA<any>();
a.refine<number>();
```

I'd like `a` to be of type `A<number>` after running the `refine` method, but it currently stays of type `A<any>`.

Comment: Not possible unfortunately. Only a typeguard can change the type of a variable and that only happens if you put it in an if. I believe there is a proposal to allow such custom type assertions but I can't find it right now

Comment: Oh that's a shame.. Thanks though!

Comment: Here is [one related issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27568).